# linux: fork/socketpair/close and multiple child process

Tags: c++, linux, fork, raii, socketpair

Right now I try to understand the forking/rebinding of *stdin/out/err* of child processes and to manage the resources (*filehandles, sockets*) rightly without leaking any resources.

There are some questions left: 
After I create a *socketpair* and fork, I have in the parent 5 filedescriptors and in the child (*stdin/out/err/socket1/socket2*). In the child process, I need to close the "parent" side of the socketpair. I close() *stdin/out/err* after the fork and *dup()* the "client end" of the socket three times. After the *dup()*, do I need to close the "source" of the dup? I guess yes ... but am I right?

When I create in this way (see below) a second child, is the resource handling right? I tried to rely heavily on RAII to not leak any fds, but is it right? Do I miss a big thing?

Bye and thanks in advance!

Georg

### EDIT: I fixed an error in rebind_and_exec_child.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#include <memory>
#include <cassert>

// this handle takes a fd, behaves like an int and makes sure the fd is closed again
class fdhandle {
public:
    explicit fdhandle(int fd) {
        mp_fd = std::shared_ptr<int>(new int, [=](int* pfd) {
            close(*pfd);
            delete pfd;
        });
        assert(mp_fd);
        *mp_fd = fd;
    }
    operator int() {
        assert(mp_fd);
        return *mp_fd;
    }
private:
    std::shared_ptr<int>    mp_fd;
};

void rebind_and_exec_child(fdhandle fd, std::string exe) {
    // now close the std fds and connect them to the given fd
    close(0);   close(1);   close(2);

    // dup the fd three times and recreate stdin/stdout/stderr with fd as the target
    if (dup(fd) != 0 || dup(fd) != 1 || dup(fd) != 2) {
        perror("error duplicating socket for stdin/stdout/stderr");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // now we can exec the new sub process and talk to it through 
    // stdin/stdout/stderr
    char *arguments[4] = { exe.c_str(), exe.c_str(), "/usr/bin", NULL };
    execv(exe.c_str(), arguments);

    // this could should never be reached
    perror("error: executing the binary");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

fdhandle fork_connected_child(std::string exe) {
    // create the socketpair
    int fd[2];
    if (-1 == socketpair(PF_LOCAL, SOCK_STREAM, 0, fd)) {
        perror("error, could not create socket pair");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    fdhandle fdparent(fd[0]);   fdhandle fdchild(fd[1]);

    // now create the child
    pid_t pid = fork();
    switch (pid) {
    case -1:    // could not fork
        perror("error forking the child");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        break;

    case 0: // child
        rebind_and_exec_child(fdchild);
        break;

    default:    // parent
        return fdparent;
        break;
    }       
}

int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
    // create 2 childs
    fdhandle fdparent1 = fork_connected_child("/bin/ls");
    fdhandle fdparent2 = fork_connected_child("/bin/ls");   
}
```

Comment: " I close() stdin/out/err after the fork and dup() the "client end" of the socket three times. " Why?

Comment: Hi, i want to talk to the child over the stdin/stdout over the connected socket. The stdin and stdout would otherwise be the console and not the socket. Am i right?

Answer (score 0):

I guess, I found the solution. For each created socket on the `socketpair()` call, I set `FD_CLOEXEC`. This way, I can be sure that the kernel closes all file descriptors. All other sockets which are handled by my code, will be closed by the fdhandle class call to `close()`. The rebinding of the stdin/stdout/stderr, I replaced the `dup()` for `dup2()` because it does close and dup atomicly.

The hint was this page:
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html

> File descriptors open in the calling process image shall remain open 
>       in the new process image, except for those whose close-on-exec flag 
>       `FD_CLOEXEC` is set.  For those file descriptors that remain open, all 
>       attributes of the open file description remain unchanged.  For any file 
>       descriptor that is closed for this reason, file locks are removed as a 
>       result of the close as described in `close()`. Locks that are not removed 
>       by closing of file descriptors remain unchanged.

This is now my adjusted code:

### EDIT: Adjusted structure

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#include <memory>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

// this handle takes a fd, behaves like an int and makes sure the fd is closed again
class fdhandle {
public:
    fdhandle()  {}
    explicit fdhandle(int fd) {
        mp_fd = std::shared_ptr<int>(new int, [=](int* pfd) {
            close(*pfd);
            delete pfd;
        });
        assert(mp_fd);
        *mp_fd = fd;

        // set FD_CLOEXEC on fd
        int flags;
        flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFD);
        if (-1 == flags) {
            perror("error, could not get flags from filedescriptor");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        flags |= FD_CLOEXEC;
        if (fcntl(fd, F_SETFD, flags) == -1) {
            perror("error, could not set FD_CLOEXEC");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    operator int() {
        assert(mp_fd);
        return *mp_fd;
    }

    void show_fd_status() {
        if (!mp_fd)
            return;

        int fd = *mp_fd;

        using namespace std;
        char buf[256];
        int fd_flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFD);
        if (fd_flags == -1)
            return;
        int fl_flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL);
        if (fl_flags == -1)
            return;
        char path[256];
        sprintf(path, "/proc/self/fd/%d", fd);
        memset(&buf[0], 0, 256);
        ssize_t s = readlink(path, &buf[0], 256);
        if (s == -1) {
            cerr << " (" << path << "): " << "not available";
            return;
        }
        cerr << fd << " (" << buf << "): ";
        // file status
        if (fd_flags & FD_CLOEXEC)  cerr << "cloexec ";
        if (fl_flags & O_APPEND)  cerr << "append ";
        if (fl_flags & O_NONBLOCK)  cerr << "nonblock ";

        // acc mode   
        if (fl_flags & O_RDONLY)  cerr << "read-only ";
        if (fl_flags & O_RDWR)  cerr << "read-write ";
        if (fl_flags & O_WRONLY)  cerr << "write-only ";
        if (fl_flags & O_DSYNC)  cerr << "dsync ";
        if (fl_flags & O_RSYNC)  cerr << "rsync ";
        if (fl_flags & O_SYNC)  cerr << "sync ";

        struct flock fl;
        fl.l_type = F_WRLCK;
        fl.l_whence = 0;
        fl.l_start = 0;
        fl.l_len = 0;
        fcntl(fd, F_GETLK, &fl);
        if (fl.l_type != F_UNLCK)
        {
            if (fl.l_type == F_WRLCK)
                cerr << "write-locked";
            else
                cerr << "read-locked";
            cerr << "(pid:" << fl.l_pid << ") ";
        }
    }
private:
    std::shared_ptr<int>    mp_fd;
};

struct child
{
    pid_t       pid;
    fdhandle    fd;
};

void rebind_and_exec_child(fdhandle fd, std::string exe) {
    // unset FD_CLOEXEC 
    int flags, oflags;
    flags = oflags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFD);
    if (-1 == flags) {
        perror("error, could not get flags from filedescriptor");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    flags &= ~FD_CLOEXEC;
    if (fcntl(fd, F_SETFD, flags) == -1) {
        perror("error, could not unset FD_CLOEXEC");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // close and rebind the stdin/stdout/stderr
    // dup the fd three times and recreate stdin/stdout/stderr with fd as the target
    if (dup2(fd, STDIN_FILENO) != 0 || dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO) != 1 || dup2(fd, STDERR_FILENO) != 2) {
        perror("error duplicating socket for stdin/stdout/stderr");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // restore the old flags
    if (fcntl(fd, F_SETFD, oflags) == -1) {
        perror("error, could not set FD_CLOEXEC");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // now we can exec the new sub process and talk to it through 
    // stdin/stdout/stderr
    char path[256];
    char argv[256];
    sprintf(path,"%s",exe.c_str());
    sprintf(argv,"%d",30);
    execlp(path, path, argv, 0);

    // this should never be reached
    perror("error: executing the binary");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

child fork_connected_child(std::string exe) {
    // create the socketpair
    int fd[2];
    if (-1 == socketpair(PF_LOCAL, SOCK_STREAM, 0, fd)) {
        perror("error, could not create socket pair");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    fdhandle fdparent(fd[0]);   fdhandle fdchild(fd[1]);

    // now create the child
    pid_t pid = fork();
    switch (pid) {
    case -1:    // could not fork
        perror("error forking the child");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        break;

    case 0: // child
        rebind_and_exec_child(fdchild, exe);
        break;

    default:    // parent
        std::cout << "forked " << exe << std::endl;
        return child { pid, fdparent };
        break;
    }       
}

int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
    // setup the signal handler prior to forking
    sleep(20);

    // create 2 childs
    {
        child child1 = fork_connected_child("/usr/bin/sleep");
        child child2 = fork_connected_child("/usr/bin/sleep");

        int status;
        waitpid(child1.pid, &status, 0);
        waitpid(child2.pid, &status, 0);
    }

    sleep(20);
}
```